# How to set Display member of combobox to a string nested within list of objects?

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, combobox

I should add that the objects are managed in a 3rd party `.dll` so I do not actually have the object definitions in my code.

I have a `List<Foo>` which I'm setting as the datasource for a `ComboBox`.

**Assuming `Foo` object looks something like:**

```
public class Foo
{
    Settings setting;
    public Foo(string title)
    {
        setting = new Settings();
        setting.Title = title;
    }
    //lots of other objects and values
}

public class Settings
{
    public Settings()
    {
    }
    public String Title {get; set;}
    //lot of other information
}
```

**And my implementation here:**

```
private void LoadList() //edited for SO testing sake, this is called in constructor
                        //of the form
{
    var foo = new List<Foo> {
        new Foo("MASTER 5DAY"),
        new Foo("5 Day Reminder"),
        new Foo("MASTER Welcome"),
        new Foo("Welcome Letter")
    };

    var master = foo.Where(x => x.Settings.Title.Contains("MASTER")).ToList();
    this.ddlMasterType = master; //This is the combobox

    //Now here I would want the display member of the ddl to be the title of each Foo object
    //But I need the value member to still contain all the other information of the Foo object
}
```

As listed in my implementation comments, I want to display the Foo.Settings.Title when I open the dropdown, but I still need the full object when I select it later.

Comment: Is this winforms? WPF? UWP? ASP.NET?

Comment: Woops my bad it is winforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in a little bit of a pickle. If you set `comboBox1.DataSource = foo;`, ordinarily you'd set `comboBox1.DisplayMember = "SomePropertyName";` and you'd be good. But in your case you need a path, not a name, and `comboBox1.DisplayMember = "settings.Title";` will be ignored.

If you could alter `Foo`, you'd just add a readonly wrapper property to `Foo`:

```
public String Title { get { return settings.Title; } }
```

But you can't alter `Foo`.

So here's an option: Write a wrapper class that you can alter.

```
public class FooCarrier
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public String Title { get { return Foo.settings.Title; } }
}
```

...

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.DataSource = new List<Foo> {
        new Foo("MASTER 5DAY"),
        new Foo("5 Day Reminder"),
        new Foo("MASTER Welcome"),
        new Foo("Welcome Letter")
    }.Select(f => new FooCarrier { Foo = f }).ToList();

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Title";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Foo";

    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  comboBox1.SelectedItem will be FooCarrier, but since we set 
    //  ValueMember to "Foo", SelectedValue is the Foo property of the selected
    //  item. 
    Foo selectedFoo = (Foo)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
}
```

You could also omit `FooCarrier` and use an anonymous type:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new List<Foo> {
    new Foo("MASTER 5DAY"),
    new Foo("5 Day Reminder"),
    new Foo("MASTER Welcome"),
    new Foo("Welcome Letter")
}.Select(f => new { Foo = f, Title = f.Settings.Title }).ToList();
```

`SelectedValue` is still `Foo`, so you'll never need to cast to the actual item type.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Wrapping my wrapper class, who knew!?

Comment: I heard you like wrapper classes.

Comment: Note that a wrapper class makes it more difficult to use the `SelectedItem` setter on the combo box.  You would need to set `SelectedItem` to an instance of the wrapper class, rather than the original data.

Comment: @Gooseberry However, the `SelectedValue` setter still works, so long as `ValueMember` is set appropriately.

Comment: @Gooseberry Yes, in that case the non-anonymous `FooCarrier` solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can set comboBox's data context as the whole list, and override ToString method of Foo class to show exactly what you want.

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return /*information you want to display, for example*/setting.Title;
    }
```

Comment: I don't have access to the `Foo` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the displayMember to the Title Property:

```
  master.DataSource = fooList;
  master.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

Get the whole object by using:

```
  Foo foo = (Foo)master.SelectedItem;
```

or

```
  Foo foo = master.SelectedItem as Foo;
```